# How to format stacktrace in log4j2?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, stack-trace

By default log4j2 prints stacktrace on multiple lines, separated by `newline` characters. Something like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: error enovountered
    at ...
    at ...
    at ...
```

I want my stacktrace on a single line, something like, essentially using `|` as a delimiter rather than `\n`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: error enovountered at ... | at ... | at ...
```

How will I accomplish something like this in log4j2?

Comment: Why? Use a GELF appender and a log consumer like graylog that can consume this. Then you get your stacktrace as one object.

Answer (score 23):

As the [`PatternLayout` documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) specifies, the `%throwable` family of conversion keys actually [support being able to change the separator used for individual stack trace elements, as well as the "cause" exceptions](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/4e47b38c4189c0b20b5b26fc982469ee76d49b95/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/ThrowableFormatOptions.java#L259-L260).

Given a pattern like:

```
[%threadName] %-5level %logger{36} - %message{nolookups}%xThrowable{separator(|)}%n
```

You'll get output like:

```
[main] ERROR my.cool.Application - Catching java.lang.RuntimeException: I'm wrapping the NPE|   at my.cool.Application.main(Application.java:24) [main/:?]|Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: This is a forced NPE| at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228) ~[?:1.8.0_121]|   at my.cool.Application.main(Application.java:21) ~[main/:?]
```

Answer (score 9):

The answers above contain the recipe. Here I am adding example:

```xml
<PatternLayout>
    <alwaysWriteExceptions>false</alwaysWriteExceptions>
    <pattern>%level;%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS};%t;%c;%enc{%msg}{CRLF};%replace{%ex}{[\r\n]{1,2}}{|}%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

If you skip the `alwaysWriteExceptions` parameter, the stack will appear twice - once linearized and once as multi-line.

Comment: I use logback and running into the same issue.Do you know if there is any parameter to avoid printing twice on loghost when using logback?

Answer (score 1):

Use `includeStacktrace` for `JsonLayout`

```
        <JsonLayout complete="false" compact="false" includeStacktrace="false">
        </JsonLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `alwaysWriteExceptions` attribute of pattern layout to false.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

Write your own exception converter that will format the exception as you wish.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#PatternConverters

And add your pattern key to the pattern of pattern layout.

Comment: seems like `alwaysWriteExceptions` will not write stacktrace, which is not the behaviour I want. From the docs, _"Setting this to false disables this behavior and allows you to exclude exceptions from your pattern output."_ 

Also, I am _not_ using `PatternLayout`, so not sure if I can use PatternConverter also.

Comment: Always writes exceptions adds a default converter to the end of the log pattern. What kind of layout are you using?