# How to format stacktrace in log4j2 using special characters?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm trying to format stacktrace printed by Log4j2 so that the separator isn't the default new line but rather a tab (\t). I did basically what was advised here: [How to format stacktrace in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789511/how-to-format-stacktrace-in-log4j2)

In the pattern I am able to use non-special characters, for example: `%xwEx{separator(|)}` will result in stack trace lines being separated by pipeline character.

However if I try this: `%xwEx{separator(\t)}` stacktrace lines aren't separated by a tab but a "\t" String like so:

java.lang.NullPointerException: error enovountered at ... \t at ... \t at ...

I tried using double backslash `\\t` but it didn't solve my problem. Is there a way to pass special characters like `\t` as the separator argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are using xml for configuration,

Referring to [Represent space and tab in XML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514635/represent-space-and-tab-in-xml-tag)

Use `&#009;` for tab.

```
%xwEx{separator(&#009;)}
```